# Mac Catalyst - control window resize

Tags: macos, window-resize, mac-catalyst

I have an app for ipad/iphone, now adding also mac support by Mac Catalyst. On Mac, I want to control window resizing, in order to allow only some sizes and aspects. It goes beyond simple minimal height and weight, or aspect. I want to allow user to resize window freely, but when app gets too high and narrow, I want to also seemlessly increase width, to keep some minimal aspect.

I believe that in AppKit it can be done through NSWindowDelegate.windowWillResize() (get user defined size, count required size and return it). However I am getting error "NSWindowDelegate is unavailable in Mac Catalyst" . Is it possible to achieve the result I want by Catalyst means?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question. It is NOT possible to create own NSWindowDelegate with windowWillResize() implemented in Catalyst. However, it IS possible to create a new target only for mac, and use it as a plugin from catalyst target.

First I load mac-only plugin (using Bundle.load() ), and instantiate its principalClass. Then I get NSWindow from UIWindow, which is easy through Dynamic library. Then I pass NSWindow to method of a plugin, which then can set own NSWindowDelegate, because it does not run in catalyst.

Sample code:

```
    guard let bundle = Bundle(url: bundleURL) else { return }
    
    let succ = bundle.load()
    if (succ) {
        let macUtilsClass = bundle.principalClass! as! MacUtilsProtocol.Type
        self.macUtils = macUtilsClass.init()
        var dnsw: NSObject? = nil
        
        
        
        if (ProcessInfo.processInfo.isOperatingSystemAtLeast(
            OperatingSystemVersion(majorVersion: 11, minorVersion: 0, patchVersion: 0))) {
           dnsw = Dynamic.NSApplication.sharedApplication.delegate.hostWindowForUIWindow(AppDelegate.ref!.window).attachedWindow
        }
        else {
            dnsw = Dynamic.NSApplication.sharedApplication.delegate.hostWindowForUIWindow(AppDelegate.ref!.window)
        }
        self.macUtils.SetupMainWindow(win: dnsw!)
    }
```